Given a focus and directrix how can a series of ellipses be described?
Since an ellipse is the locus of points that has a constant ratio of distance between a focus (point) and a directrix (line), where that constant ratio is between 0 and 1, my conjecture is that given a focus and a directrix, there is one unique ellipse.
However, I came across the following problem:
"With a given point and line as focus and directrix, a series of ellipses are described; prove that the locus of the extremities of their minor axis is a parabola."
(See: https://tardigrade.in/question/with-a-given-point-and-line-as-focus-and-directrix-a-series-7lejwy48)
I am unable to think of a case where more than one ellipse may be described given a focus and the corresponding directrix.

For unique ellipse 3 things are required : focus, directrix and eccentricity. According to question, if eccentricity varies, keeping one focus and corresponding directrix same, infinitely many ellipses can be generated. You have find locus of extremities of minor axes of all those ellipses.

An ellipse is uniquely determined by its focus, its directrix, and its eccentricity $e$ (the measure of elongation). Note $e = 0$ is a circle and $e = 1$ is a parabola.
For a fixed focus and directrix, we can construct an ellipse of any eccentricity $0 < e < 1$ with said focus and directrix.
